# Convert T-SQL table-valued function string split into C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to convert a T-SQL table-valued function into c# code. This function splits a string by a delimiter. input sample E,U7619

Is there a way to convert the logic into c# code?

I have tried several things but they are to pathetic to post here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitText]
    (@text VARCHAR(8000), 
     @delimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS @words TABLE (objectid SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY, string VARCHAR(1000), optionalid INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos smallint,
            @i smallint,
            @j smallint,
            @s varchar(255),
            @o int

    SET @pos = 1

    WHILE @pos <= LEN(@text)
    BEGIN
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(' ', @text, @pos)
        SET @j = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @text, @pos)

        IF @i > 0 OR @j > 0
        BEGIN
            IF @i = 0 OR (@j > 0 AND @j < @i)
                SET @i = @j

            IF @i > @pos
            BEGIN
                -- @i now holds the earliest delimiter in the string
                SET @s = SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, @i - @pos)
                SET @o = 0
                IF CHARINDEX('|',@s,0) > 0
                    BEGIN
                        SET @o = SUBSTRING(@s,0,CHARINDEX('|',@s,0))
                        SET @s = SUBSTRING(@s,CHARINDEX('|',@s,0)+1,LEN(@s))

                    END

                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @words WHERE [string]=@s)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @words
                    VALUES (@pos, @s, @o)
                END
            END

            SET @pos = @i + 1
            WHILE @pos < LEN(@text) AND SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, 1) IN (' ', ',')
                SET @pos = @pos + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @s = SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, LEN(@text) - @pos + 1)
            IF CHARINDEX('|',@s,0) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @o = SUBSTRING(@s,0,CHARINDEX('|',@s,0))
                SET @s = SUBSTRING(@s,CHARINDEX('|',@s,0)+1,LEN(@s))

            END

            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @words WHERE [string]=@s)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @words
                VALUES (@pos, @s ,@o)
            END

            SET @pos = LEN(@text) + 1
        END
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: C# already has a `string.Split` function. The reason you have such nasty code in SQL is because it does not.

Comment: "Is there a way to convert the logic into c# code?" - as C# code that can be called purely in C#? sure: you rewrite it line by line based on understanding what it does and why; you'd have to do it manually, and it may end up looking very differently, because C# and TSQL are very different. BTW, SQL Server has a `string_split` function built-in which will perform **much** better than a loop

Comment: @DStanley *cough* [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) *cough*

Comment: @MarcGravell Which is only available in SQL Server 2016 and newer.

Comment: There are better ways to split strings in t-sql but c# is going to be faster no matter how you slice it. Jeff Moden has a lightning fast splitter [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function). Some other options can be found [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: ...and if you have the data in C# to start, [stop splitting anywhere near the database at all](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql).

Comment: This is very complicated to read, but without a doubt it will become amazingly simple and obvious if you post examples of the data it's splitting and what it's trying to get out of each string. Can you share that? Then instead of reverse-engineering the SQL the problem becomes "How do we get the values we want out of this `string`?"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your just splitting the data on a pipe.  Try this:

```
var testdata = "test|example|splitting|words";
var foo = testdata.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: It's not. It's splitting the data based on whatever @delimiter is. And the pipe is somewhere in the picture too. Based on that it's not clear what that SQL does, but it's definitely not just splitting based on one delimiter.